# I cant get the Calendar to shift months

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

I cant get the code to get The previous month (I am trying to get the previous month first, then I can do the same for the year and for getting the next month / year. 
I cant use JTable nor can I use Drag and Drop.

I have tried to add an action listener to the button, and making the month -1 but it did not work.

```
public CalendarLayout () {
    monthm = new JButton("<");
    monthm.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
          public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {

              cal.add(Calendar.MONTH, -1);
                updateMonth();
            //    monthPanel(cal);

          }
        });
    monthp = new JButton(">");
    monthp.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
          public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
            cal.add(Calendar.MONTH, +1);
          }
        });
    yearm = new JButton("<<");
    yearp = new JButton(">>");

    day_name = new JLabel [7];
    dayss = new JButton [42];
    this.monthPanel((GregorianCalendar) cal);   

}

    int getDay(int m)
    {
        GregorianCalendar g1=new GregorianCalendar();
        g1.set(cal.get(cal.YEAR),m, 1);
        return g1.get(g1.DAY_OF_WEEK);

    }
    boolean is31(int m)

    {


        boolean b=false;
        if(m>=0&&m<=6)
        {
            for(int i=1;i<8;i++)
            {
                if(m%2==0)
                {
                    b= true;
                }
            }
        }
        else  {
            for(int i=7;i<12;i++)
            {
                if(m%2==1)
                {
                    b= true;
                }

            }
        }
        return b;
    }
    void monthPanel(GregorianCalendar cl)
    {
        pCal=new JPanel();
        pCal.setLayout(new GridLayout(7,7));
        int month=cl.MONTH+1;
        //System.out.println("left");
        int fd=getDay(month)-1;

        for(int i=0;i<7;i++)
        {
            day_name[i]=new JLabel (days[i]);
            pCal.add(day_name[i]);
        }
        boolean b=is31(month);
        if(month==1)
        {
            int count=0;
            for(int i=fd-1 ;i>=0;i--,count++)
            {
                dayss[count]=new JButton(31-i+"");
                dayss[count].setEnabled(false);

            }
            if(((GregorianCalendar) cal).isLeapYear(cl.YEAR))
            {
                for(int i=1;i<=29;i++,count++)
                {
                    dayss[count]=new JButton(i+"");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                for(int i=1;i<=28;i++,count++)
                {
                    dayss[count]=new JButton(i+"");
                }
            }
            for(int i=count,c=1;i<42;i++,c++,count++)
            {
                dayss[count]=new JButton(c+"");
                dayss[count].setEnabled(false);


            }
        } 
        else if(month==2)
        {

            int count=0;
            for(int i=fd-1 ;i>=0;i--,count++)
            {
                if(((GregorianCalendar) cal).isLeapYear(cl.YEAR))
                {
                    dayss[count]=new JButton(29-i+"");
                    dayss[count].setEnabled(false);
                }
                else
                {
                    dayss[count]=new JButton(28-i+"");
                    dayss[count].setEnabled(false);
                }

            }
            for(int i=1;i<32;i++,count++)
            {
                dayss[count]=new JButton(i+"");
            }
            for(int i=count,c=1;i<42;i++,c++,count++)
            {
                dayss[count]=new JButton(c+"");
                dayss[count].setEnabled(false);

            }

        }
        else if(!b||month==0||month==7||month==0)
        {

                int count=0;
                for(int i=fd-1 ;i>=0;i--,count++)
                {

                    dayss[count]=new JButton(31-i+"");
                    dayss[count].setEnabled(false);
                }
                if(month==7||month==0)
                    for(int i=1;i<32;i++,count++)
                    {
                        dayss[count]=new JButton(i+"");
                    }
                else
                {   
                    for(int i=1;i<31;i++,count++)
                    {
                        dayss[count]=new JButton(i+"");
                    }
                }
                for(int i=count,c=1;i<42;i++,c++,count++)
                {
                    dayss[count]=new JButton(c+"");
                    dayss[count].setEnabled(false);

                }
        }

        else if(month!=1)
        {
            {

                int count=0;
                for(int i=fd-1 ;i>=0;i--,count++)
                {
                    dayss[count]=new JButton(30-i+"");
                    dayss[count].setEnabled(false);

                }
                for(int i=1;i<32;i++,count++)
                {
                    dayss[count]=new JButton(i+"");
                }
                for(int i=count,c=1;i<42;i++,c++,count++)
                {
                    dayss[count]=new JButton(c+"");
                    dayss[count].setEnabled(false);

                }
            }

        }

        for(int i=0;i<42;i++)
        {
            pCal.add(dayss[i]);
        }
        PCalendar.add(pCal,BorderLayout.CENTER);    

}

      void updateMonth() {
            cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);


            String month = cal.getDisplayName(Calendar.MONTH, Calendar.LONG, Locale.US);
            int year = cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);
            monthYear.setText(month + " " + year);

         //   int startDay = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
          //  int numberOfDays = cal.getActualMaximum(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);


           monthPanel(cal);

      }





          }
```

I am expecting to get the right GUI for the previous month when pressing the button.

Comment: Please shrink that code a bit. Way too many lines of code are given in the snippet :)

Comment: @WaleedTiti Have you tried debugging? Do you know when it starts behaving incorrectly?

Comment: It does not change, the month seems to not update. Although the label that I have the Month and the Year in is working properly, but the gridLayout is not changing. It is stuck to April.

Comment: So when you click on the button, does the action event fire (get called)?

Comment: Yes it does, I have added a print statement the month indeed does decrement, but it does not update on the GUI.

Comment: Have you tried removing the old JPanel from the contentPane? I think based on your code, your contentPane is called `PCalendar`. Try this... `PCalendar.remove(--someExistingJPanel--);`

Comment: I have tried it actually.

Comment: In your code, where did you put that `contentPane.remove(jpanel)`?

Comment: in the updateMonth function

Comment: Is `PCalendar` a global or local variable?

Comment: Logically, it doesn't make sense that it didn't work, so I'm thinking that if `contentPane.remove(jPanel)` isn't working, there might be something that's preventing that function from firing.

Comment: If you want, if you have a GitHub account, you can create a secret gist with the full code and have me look it over and I'll try to help you out. No pressure though. (Secret gists can be deleted by their author -- the author who has a GitHub account).

Comment: https://github.com/WaleedTiti99/ToDoList sure here you go

Comment: Interesting... I actually see it working. The only change I made was changing `lay.setSize(500,600)` to `lay.setSize(1000,600)` in **Test.java**. Hrmm. Try changing it to that and try it out. I think it's rather odd that it's not working for you. Which IDE are you using? Eclipse?

Comment: Any luck on figuring this out?